# Postgres connect existing local server after windows reinstall

Tags: postgresql

i had Postgresql server on my local disc (F), after i reinstalled windows disk (C), an now i want to connect to my Postgresql server with pg admin 4, is it possible? i have create one function there and i want to recover it, if it is possible.

i tried server names - 'localhost', 'postgres', but message is - unable to connect to server: could not translate name .... to address: unknown host.

may be something to be changed in config file?

or may be pd admin to be installed on the same disk?